# How do you add something to the Unity Launcher that only appears in the Dash? (Such as Chrome Web App Shortcuts)

Tags: unity, unity-dash, google-chrome, webapps

I use Google Chrome/Chromium's Create Shortcut Feature and when I opted to make the shortcut, I chose to not make a Desktop Icon and have it only appear in the Dash.

However, I want to Lock it to the Launcher as a separate app from Google Chrome but when I click to open the app it opens under the normal Google Chrome Icon on the Unity Launcher so I can't pin it that way.

I think if I had a desktop shortcut, I could just drag it onto the launcher?

A Solution to this would to allow Right-Clicking in the Dash in the next release of Ubuntu so you can right-click and say "Lock to Launcher".

But till then I need a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drag the icon from the Dash into the Launcher.

Comment: Thanks... That is so simple but so easy to not think of...

Comment: Is it possible to have the separate window register with the new icon, so that an arrow appears next to this dragged icon instead of the chromium icon (by messing with the shortcut file)?

Comment: As far as I know that's usually not possible as the launcher groups applications not by shortcut file content but by some window properties